# Are traps really required for a 3D Bose Einstein condensate?

Tags: phase-transition, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons, ion-traps

I came across this article that claims to a have a B.E condensate of exciton polariton in 2D. However, the authors also seem to admit that is a different kind of phase transition different from a traditional BEC and called Kosterlitz-Thouless superfluid (KTS) transition. But the condensate properties of this are similar to that of atomic BEC. A special condition for this KTS was requirement of a potential trap which in context of paper was local minima provided by disordered potential well. So I was wondering in this context that: Are trap really required for a 3D BEC ??

The discussed paper is from J. Kasprzak et al., Nature 443, 409 (2006). https://www.nature.com/articles/nature05131

Here is a piece from the supplementary information of the paper that discusses about KT.

[image]

Comment: KT transition has nothing to do with trap. Rather, it is because the system is (classical) 2D. The finite temperature superfluid transition is of KT type in 2D.

Comment: Where, in that paper, do they mention KT?

Comment: @SuperCiocia They have mentioned that in the supplementary information.